# Download an xlsx file in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, xlsx

I am trying to download a *.xlsx* file into my project's resources using the following execution:

```
<execution>
    <id>${id}</id>
    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>wget</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <url>${url}</url>
        <outputFileName>${fileOutput}</outputFileName>
        <outputDirectory>${licensesDir}/em</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

However, the file that it generates is empty and cannot be read. I know it's not a problem with the file I'm trying to download because whenever I download it directly and copy it into my project manually, I can read it it fine, and it works with my code. It also downloads other file types just fine.

Yet, whenever I try to do download it this way, in the *pom.xml*, the generated file is empty and my code generates a `NullPointerException` exception when run.

Could anyone provide some help please?

Comment: Why do you like to download it. Why not putting it into the projects resource directory ?

Comment: The file is often edited, so I need it to be updated whenever the project is built.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is Maven Download Plugin: https://github.com/maven-download-plugin/maven-download-plugin

Add plugin to your pom and execute goal like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>download-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install-jbpm</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>wget</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/jbpm/jBPM%203/jbpm-3.1.4/jbpm-3.1.4.zip</url>
                <unpack>true</unpack>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jbpm-3.1.4</outputDirectory>
                <md5>df65b5642f33676313ebe4d5b69a3fff</md5>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. I had already added the plugin and it's what I'm using to download the file. It is working fine for other file types (e.g. .csv files). However, the problem comes whenever I try to use the plugin to download .xlsx files.

Comment: Maybe because this plugin can't work on generate-sources phase. You can try to change the phase to: <phase>prepare-package</phase>